# Fire onTabChanged() programmatically

Tags: android, events

If I have a listener for changed tab like this:

```
        mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 0) {
                 //..
            }
            else if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 1) {
                 //..
            }
            else if (mTabHost.getCurrentTab() == 2) {
                 //..
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I fire the `onTabChanged()` method programmatically?

Comment: If I were you I would swap this IF/ELSE for a SWITCH statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call,

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTab(id);
```

Or

```
mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(tag);
```

For reference,

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Comment: Thanks! This way it works. I was trying to use `mTabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(id)` which doesn't work...